# default-value for ndb.StringProperty are not set at my App Engine-app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I save users in App Engine's NDB. Some values are required but unnessesary so I wish them set to default-values if unavailable.
When I create a User(primaryEmail="example@dom.com"), the default value seem to be an empty string:

```
User(key=Key('User', 4523189241643008),familyName=u'', givenName=u'', primaryEmail=u'example@dom.com')

class User(ndb.Model):
  primaryEmail              = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  givenName                 = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, default='<name>')
  familyName                = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, default='<surname>')
```

Are there some limitation to setting default-values for StringProperties that I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out the '<...>' characters caused the problem.

Comment: What?  How did they cause a problem?  That's a surprise to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide empty strings as parameters, NDB will store them.

```
..., familyName=u'', givenName=u'', ...
```

If you don't provide the parameters, it will use the default values.

```
User(key=Key('User', 4523189241643008), primaryEmail=u'example@dom.com')
```

Note: This also means that you can't make those fields required:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  primaryEmail              = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  givenName                 = ndb.StringProperty(default='<name>')
  familyName                = ndb.StringProperty(default='<surname>')
```

Comment: That's how it should work, but my experience is something different. I'm sure that I only set primaryEmail.

Comment: If I remove default, I get: BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties: givenName, familyName

Comment: I updated my answer with a note to remove the `required=true` arguments

Comment: Removing required changes nothing in my case, I'm afraid.